# Extracting types from boost:hana::set with partial specialization fails

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-hana

I'm using the following template to declare a set of types:

```
template<class ...T>
using DependencySet = boost::hana::set<boost::hana::type<T>...>;
```

I would like to be able to extract those types back from the set and put in another container. I tried using a "classic" approach:

```
template<class ...T>
struct ExtractTypes;

template<class ...Dependencies>
struct ExtractTypes<DependencySet<Dependencies...>>
{
    using type = SomeOtherType<Dependencies...>;
};
```

Alas, the compiler disagrees:

> error: class template partial specialization contains a template
>   parameter that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will
>   never be used [-Wunusable-partial-specialization]
>
> struct ExtractTypes< DependencySet< Dependencies...>>

Is there a way to extract the types back from such set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to the compiler error, I think it is incorrect and you are probably using an older version of Clang or GCC.

Even with an up to date compiler your code is incorrect because it is making assumptions about the template parameters of [`hana::set`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1set.html) which are documented as **implementation defined** since `set` is meant to be an unordered associative container.

Consider using the "types as values" approach which allows more expressive code, and it is what Boost.Hana is meant to facilitate.

For making a set, use [`hana::make_set`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1set.html#af38c23fb98d8eec68c1491a8bca9ce43), and to get the values back out you can use [`hana::unpack`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Foldable.html#ga7b0c23944364ce61136e10b978ae2170) which calls a variadic function object with its contained values (in no specific order).

Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename ...T>
struct DependencySet { };

int main()
{
  auto deps = hana::make_set(
    hana::type<char>{}
  , hana::type<int>{}
  , hana::type<long>{}
  );

  auto dep_types = hana::unpack(deps, hana::template_<DependencySet>);

  static_assert(
    hana::typeid_(dep_types) == hana::type<DependencySet<char, int, long>>{}
  , ""
  );

}
```

As an aside, if you just want to put template parameters from one template into another, take a look at Boost.Mp11's [`mp_apply`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_applyf_l)

Comment: You're right - I should have gone with the hana approach all along. Thanks!